# Collection callback ignoring scope variable

Tags: javascript, meteor

Is there some reason the following `data.id` variable shows up in the console as `undefined`?

```
  Meteor.methods({
        'productUpdate': function(_data) {

            var data = {
                id: _data.id,
                name: _data.name.trim(),
                sku: _data.sku.toUpperCase(),
                retail: _data.retail
            };

            Products.update(data.id, {$set: data}, function(error, result) {

                console.log(data.id); // <------ WHY DOES THIS OUTPUT 'undefined'

                if(error)
                    throw new Meteor.Error('validation', error.message, error.invalidKeys[0].name);
                if(result)
                    logActivity('Products', data.id, 'Product updated');
            });
        }
    });
```

I'm pretty confused, but I must be missing something basic. Other variables work if I define them outside the callback, e.g. even the passed in `_data.id` returns a value.

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(data)`?

Comment: Good point, I receive a modified object back... weirdly it has several fields, although not all, but doesn't include the id. It seems like the update() is mutating the data object. Is this normal?

Comment: Are you using some package which interferes with collections? Like collection-hooks or collection2?

Comment: Oh yeh, actually I am using Collection2... I'll check the docs.

Comment: I can't seem to see a documented reason why this happens, is this Collection2 interfering with the callback return?

Comment: It looks like Collection2 is modifying the `data` object in-place, without making a defensive clone... try sending `{$set: EJSON.clone(data)}` instead of `{$set: data}` and see if makes any difference.

Comment: Yep, you nailed it. That's exactly what is happening. Please post this as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Collection2 is modifying the `data` object in-place without making a defensive clone. Try making a clone yourself:

```
Products.update(data.id, {$set: EJSON.clone(data)}, function () ...)
```

Comment: This may actually be due to SimpleSchema doing a clean on validation, not specifically Collection2.